# Search for substring in string with specific conditions

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to figure out, what is a proper way to search sub string in other string to get equal outputs for content example:

```
hello how are you
```

with true for inputs:

```
hey hello how are you ok
how are you 
are you
```

and false for this:

```
you
how you are ok you
howareyou
howok
how you
hey hello
```

I want true with equal phrase or part of phrase contained in a string, but not individual words or words in another sequence. This way it true for all with  `(aList.Any(input.Contains))` and false for all with `(aList.Contains(input))`:

```
        List<string> aList = new List<string>() {
                                                 "hey hello how are you ok",
                                                 "how are you",
                                                 "are you",
                                                 "you",
                                                 "how you are ok you",
                                                 "howareyou",
                                                 "howok",
                                                 "how you",
                                                 "hey hello" };

            string input = "hello how are you";  

            foreach (string a in aList)
            {
                if (a.Any(input.Contains))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + " - true");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + " - false");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("__\n\r");

            foreach (string a in aList)
            {
                if (a.Contains(input))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + " - true");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + " - false");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, give a real name to List.

Comment: If you can describe in words what constitutes a true, and what a false, result, then it would be possible. Otherwise, you'll have to list and compare all the true and false possibilities.

Comment: What is your reasoning to return `true ` for "are you" but `false` for "you" ?

Comment: @Andy G hello, I want true with equal phrase or part of phrase contained in a string, but not individual words or words in another sequence

Comment: @Greggz hello, yes part of phrase, but not one word

Comment: I guess you would have to define how you want to split the phrase in subphrases. It seems you need to check the entire phrase then split and check without the first word then split and check again without the first word until only two words are left in the phrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> aList = new List<string>()
        {"hey hello how are you ok", "how are you", "are you", "you", "how you are ok you", "howareyou", "howok", "how you", "hey hello"};


        var input = "hello how are you";

        // build matcher
        string[] chunks = input.Split(' ');
        string matcher = "";
        for (int i = chunks.Length, j = 0; i > 1; i--, j++){
            var matcherPart = new string [i];
            Array.Copy(chunks, j, matcherPart, 0, i);
            matcher += "("+String.Join(@"+\s+", matcherPart) + ")";
        }
        matcher = matcher.Replace(")(", ")|(");

        // Console.WriteLine(matcher);
        //(hello+\s+how+\s+are+\s+you)|(how+\s+are+\s+you)|(are+\s+you)";


        foreach (string a in aList)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(matcher, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match m = r.Match(a);
            Group g = m.Groups[0];
            Console.WriteLine(a + " - " + (g.Captures.Count > 0));
        }

        /*

        hey hello how are you ok - True
        how are you - True
        are you - True
        you - False
        how you are ok you - False
        howareyou - False
        howok - False
        how you - False
        hey hello - False

        */
    }
}
```

The build matcher part creates regexp with possible combinations, i.e this string `a b c d` is being transformed to this: `(a+b+c+d)|(b+c+d)|(c+d)`. Having that you can easily loop through your list values and apply regexp. The `g.Captures.Count` tells you whether your list's item is matched to your patters or not.

Comment: A little explanation of why this solves the problem would really improve the quality of your answer

Comment: Well the `build matcher` part creates regexp with possible combinations, i.e this string `a b c d` is being transformed to this: `(a)|(b)|(c)|(d)`. Having that you can easily loop through your list values and apply regexp. The `g.Captures.Count` tells you whether you list's item is matched to your patters or not.

Comment: Sounds good. Why don't you add it to the answer. We all are here to learn and explanations are the key to it. You will see it on the amount of up votes at your answers. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

This should work for now as you didn't specifiy anything else. At least 2 words present to `return true`

```
string [] array = input.Split(' ');

    foreach(string a in list)
    {
        bool yes = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length-1; ++i ){
            string test = array[i] + " " + array[i+1];
            if(a.Contains(test)){
                yes = true;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(yes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would divide this problem into 2 steps.

1) `Split` the input by `' '` (space) and make a collection of all possible `subphrases` that can be matched:

```
string input = "hello how are you";

string[] inputParts = input.Split(' ');

List<string> subphrases = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < inputParts.Length-1; i++)
{
    subphrases.Add(string.Join(" ", inputParts.Skip(i)));
}
```

2) Take from your corpus / `aList` only those items `Where` one item `Contains` `Any` of the elements in your `subphrases` collection:

```
List<string> all_TRUE_Matches = aList.Where(
                   corpusItem => subphrases.Any(sub => corpusItem.Contains(sub))).ToList();
```

The order in the code is different from my sentence. `Any` will return `true` for every `corpusItem` in `aList` which `Contains` at least 1 element from the `subphrases` collection. (I hope this is more clear ;) )

To get a list of `FALSE` matches simply negate the `Any` condition:

```
List<string> all_FALSE_Matches = aList.Where(
                   corpusItem => !subphrases.Any(sub => corpusItem.Contains(sub))).ToList();
```